# Cannot Convert class in Json

Tags: javascript, charts, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I want a make some chart, based on class Result (i use CodeFirst)

I have class Results.cs

```
   using System;

namespace PersonalArea.DAL.Models
{
    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string PatientId { get; set; }

        public string GameName { get; set; }

        public string Time { get; set; }

        public int Score { get; set; }

        public int Level { get; set; }

        public DateTime FirstEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEnter { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateExit { get; set; }

        public string DifficultLevel { get; set; }

        public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And method in controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Results(string id)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            Patient patient = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id) as Patient;
            if (patient == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            List<IGrouping<string, Result>> results = _context.Results.Where(x => x.PatientId == id).GroupBy(z => z.GameName).ToList();
            ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
            return View(results);
        }
```

And view.cshtml

```
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            var test = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.test);
            var datapoints = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
                datapoints.push({ y: test[i].Score, x: test[i].ID, label: test[i].GameName });
            }
window.onload = function () {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme: "theme2",
                animationEnabled: true,
                title: {
                    text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
                },
                subtitles: [
                    { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
                ],
                data: [
                {
                        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                        dataPoints: datapoints
                    /*[
                    { x: 10, y: 71 },
                    { x: 20, y: 55 },
                    { x: 30, y: 50 },
                    { x: 40, y: 65 },
                    { x: 50, y: 95 },
                    { x: 60, y: 68 },
                    { x: 70, y: 28 },
                    { x: 80, y: 34 },
                    { x: 90, y: 14 }
                    ]*/
                                        //Uncomment below line to add data coming from the controller.
                    //dataPoints: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),
                }
                ]
            });
            chart.render();
        };

        }
```

But system showed error

JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'PersonalArea.DAL.Models.Result'. Path '[0][0].patient.results'.

On

ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);

Please, help my resolve this error

Answer (score 0):

You have a self-reference in the type `Patient`, what this means is that the `Patient` class has a property of `Patient` or `Result` type what could generate a infinite cycle when the serializer try to walk property by property recursively in order to generate the final string.

Comment: And how i can resolve this problem? Try make a class, unrelated with class Patient and work with him?

Comment: Use a ViewModel class. I suppose you are using your `Patient` class as one of your model in your application. The advantage of using your ViewModel classes is that it let you represents the data as it is going to be shown in your app, not the way it is stored in the database. In the ViewModel, do not make any self-reference property

Comment: And this ViewModel i can convert on Json on controller?

Comment: Yes, the `PatientViewModel` can have similar properties as the `Patient` model, as soon as it does not hold reference pointing each other it will serialize.

Comment: Okey, i tryed. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occurs when you have object A that's one of the parameters is object B which has a reference to the object A. Let me write it in a code:

```
class A
{
   //some fields
   public B BField{get; set;}
}
class B
{
   //some fields
   public A AField{get; set;}
}
```

In this case if in your A object has BField != null and this field's AField is targeting the A object, then you have a loop. One of the easiest ways of getting rid of it is to make this field = null just before you send the data to the client's side.

For example:

```
A a = new A();
a.BField = new B();
//your operations on A object
//now, just before you will send it
a.BField.AField = null;
```

That should do the trick. Probably in your "Patient" class you have a field that targets Result class or another complex type field that targets Result class. Just null the reference and it should work.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Please, can you show approximately how it may can in my class and where? In controller or class?

Comment: I don't know the structure of "Patient" and "DifficultLevel" classes. If you would copy them here, I could be more precised. But, let's assume that the problem is "Patient" class because of the Result field which is Result type. 

So in your controller, just before line: "ViewBag.Test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);" do this:

results.forEach(x=>{x.Patient.Result = null;});

That should do the trick :)